Where to put Community Toolkit Long Press on MAUI CollectionView Item
I have a CollectionView of items.  I want to long press on an item to cause navigation to call the LongPressCommand.
The DataTemplate of the items is 3 labels.
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding FormattedEvents}" 
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                    EmptyView="No events recorded."
                    HeightRequest="500" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMatchEvent}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">

        <CollectionView.Behaviors>
            <!--THIS WILL WORK IF I LONG PRESS ON THE EMPTY LIST-->
            <toolkit:TouchBehavior LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressCommand}"/>
        </CollectionView.Behaviors>

        
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Grid.Behaviors>
                        <!--DOESN'T WORK-->
                        <toolkit:TouchBehavior LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressCommand}"/>
                    </Grid.Behaviors>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                   Grid.Column="0" 
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   Text="{Binding HomeEventMessage}"
                                   FontSize="Medium">
                        <Label.Behaviors>
                            <!--DOESN'T WORK-->
                            <toolkit:TouchBehavior LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressCommand}"/>
                        </Label.Behaviors>
                    </Label>

                    <Label Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                       Grid.Column="1" 
                                       TextColor="White"
                                       Text="{Binding EventTime}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       FontSize="Default"/>
                    
                    <Label Grid.Column="3"
                                   Text="{Binding AwayEventMessage}"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   FontSize="Medium" >
                        <Label.Behaviors>
                            <!--DOESN'T WORK-->
                            <toolkit:TouchBehavior LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressCommand}"/>
                        </Label.Behaviors>
                    </Label>
                    
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>


When using Bindings for a Behaviour, you may use a x:Reference Binding expression.
Let's say you have a LongPressCommand in ViewModel which the ContentPage binds to. Then you may use x:reference Binding expression for the element like below,
First, set the name of the page to "this",
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     ...
     x:Name="this">

Use x:Reference to bind,
<DataTemplate>
    ...
                <Grid.Behaviors>
                    <!--DOESN'T WORK-->
                    <toolkit:TouchBehavior LongPressCommand="{Binding BindingContext.LongPressCommand,Source={x:Reference this}}"/>
                </Grid.Behaviors>
</DataTemplate>

The same goes for the Label Control in DataTemplate.
Please let me know if you have any question.

Thank you.  This hits the command in the code behind but seems to block the much needed SelectedItem

That's true, gesture conflict.

I thought a timer under the hood would have kept them seperated?

But the question is the default collectionview selection is blocked.

I think one workaround is adding an extra click command, in which implement the logic to select the Item.

such as,     <toolkit:TouchBehavior Command="{Binding BindingContext.TapCommand,Source={x:Reference this}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" LongPressCommand="{Binding BindingContext.LongPressCommand,Source={x:Reference this}}"                            LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
